# Enabling configuration storage in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have followed the directions, created a control user and database, ran the create_tables.sql script (after I modified it with the proper DB name), used the setup script to create a config file and filled out all the fields on the "Edit Server -> Configuration Storage" page. I moved the generated config file into the top level PMA directory.

I can use PMA fine, but the Configuration Storage features aren't working. The foreign key fields aren't hyperlinking to their respective entities in different fields. I've checked the configuration tables (pma_*), and they're all empty except for pma_recent, which has two entries (login attempts or something?).

I should note that I built the DB before installing phpMyAdmin, so is there some script or something I have to run for it to scan the current tables and find the foreign keys/links?

Thanks!

Comment: if your PMA is not working correctly, install mysql command line and try with mysqldump or load file, if not, try to update the PMA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always had the same problem. I could never get the pma configuration database to work. SQL history neither.

Now phpMyAdmin has browser storage, which luckily works. Except it's nagging me on every refresh [or new tab] to load the configuration from the browser storage.

I just rely on the php config, and put everything in there.

Comment: They have changed phpMyAdmin to a new release that stinks. The new release is full of bells and whistles like ajax and other half cooked craps that makes you waste time and do not works. The installation process do not configures the stuff completely and leaves a lot of stuff half configured, like storage and permissions. I am having a hard time figuring out their awful documentation. Have you ever managed to make this work? thanks.

Comment: No, and I stopped wasting time with it.

Comment: I have downgraded today the whole interface to phpMyAdmin 2.5. It is ugly like hell but works. Since phpMyAdmin 3.x and up, it stinks with a lot of bugs (you press edit it inserts a new record, for example) that they never cared to solve. On the other hand, they waste their times creating """""fancy""""" (with a lot of quotes) visuals that were never properly tested and just work on some browsers and annoy everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Configurations of phpMyAdmin is in the file config.inc.php and you can take a look on this file config.sample.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me `$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;`
Thanks to http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3998/